# JS & PHP Date/Time (Daylight Savings)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, datetime

Ok, so there is a couple of questions in here all relating to the way JS & PHP handle dates for different timezones.

Now, I was under the impression that JS uses the clients System Time, however, I am based in the UK and the current time is 21:12 but the JS `new Date()` function is showing 20:12. Now this is down to daylight savings.
My first question is this:

Can JS detect timezones and adjust the time accordingly? My app is to be used in various countries and the use of the date is a check to see when the last search was done and check if any new results have been added since then.

My second question is if the above is too difficult/complicated I could always do the processing in PHP on the server side. Currently the JS is passing the time as a unix timestamp and PHP is then converting it to the MYSQL time to query the database. So what could do in PHP to ensure that the correct time is being passed to the query?

Comment: Would suggest using UNIX timestamps at GMT for everything except display and use MomentJS library to help with any formatting or parsing or math on time.

Comment: Time zones are a huge PITA and accurately determining what the local time was anywhere at a particular point in history depends on the mechanisms used to keep time and the type of calendar and the DST rules for the region (which vary insanely since no universal/international body dictates any of this).  There are databases for resolving these issues but unless it's a huge priority/issue it's probably not worth getting into that can of worms.  The error you see in DST may be a problem with the specific system settings or DST rules that changed since programmed. (had to vent)

Comment: I completely understand. I've been looking at this for ages now, trying to think of ways etc. And as you can imagine, in this situation I do need accurate times as it is cruicial that only new items are returned from the DB based on the created_at date in the table which seems to be storing correctly. I may have to dig around in Laravel so see how it sets the correct time.

Comment: Yup like I said originally personally I get everything into a GMT time for storage purposes and just keep it that way until it needs to be displayed, that should resolve the issue technically speaking, but in terms of the display date and figuring out what a time was exactly at the time it was recorded accounting for the DST time (at the time a time-stamp was made) is where you need to start relying on libraries/databases/services that can figure out the right answer.  Insofar as X happened before now or Y Minutes in the past GMT time for everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

JS can detect local time. You can use
   Date().getTimezoneOffset()
to calculate timezone difference between UTC and Local Time.

You can read more about it [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/date_gettimezoneoffset.htm)